# Manage permissions on File storage share

Tags: azure

I am experimenting with File Storage on Azure and have successfully created a share, that I can mount from my Windows machine like this:

```
net use [drive] \\[storage account].file.core.windows.net\[share] /u:[user] [pass]
```

But, it looks like the [user] and [account] are always the same. Is it possible to mount the share with another user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The user/pass token is per share. ACLs or AD based authentication is still in the to-do list. The only workaround would be using shared access signatures (SAS) via the REST API or the client libraries.

> Using SAS, you can generate tokens with specific permissions that are
>   valid over a specified time interval. For example, you can generate a
>   token with read-only access to a given file. Anyone who possesses this
>   token while it is valid has read-only access to that file.

But SAS is only supported via the REST API or client libraries, that means mounting the file share via the SMB protocol (your case) wouldn't work.

**Update**:

User and Url path change, but storage key remains the same if the same storage is used.

Comment: Is the user/pass token per share or per storage account?

Comment: My mistake. Per storage. Url and user change based on the share name, but the storage token is the same unless you create a new share in a different storage.